# Is there a way to implement global computed property in Python?

Tags: python, variables, global

In Swift we can do the following, at any scope (including inside another function):

```
var X:Int = 3
var twiceX:Int{
    return 2*X
}
print(twiceX) //6
```

This means we can call a getter function without using the "()" syntax. Any function that takes no argument and return one value can also be implemented as a computer property. Additionally, it is also possible to provide a setter function.

I see that it is possible to make computed properties that belong to classes, using @property declarator, but I see no way to make this a global one. I would expect anything possible at class scope, should be possible at global scope.

Are there global computed properties in Python?

Remarks: I understand that it is mostly a synthetic sugar, that eliminates one pair of ‘()’ every call. However, there are cases where a property is more intuitive than a function. An example is:

```
queue = [1,4,7]
def current():
    return queue[0]
```

This is used for the same reason that computed properties is seen in classes: as a presentation of a property, without storing the same information twice.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you want `current` to evaluate to `queue[0]`?

Comment: In short, no, because global variables are just accessed by dictionary lookup, generally speaking. One can sort-of achieve something like this at the module level by subclassing `ModuleType` and doing wild things, but that still won't change how globals are accessed; only attributes on the module object itself.

Comment: Can you show a specific usage? Is it just sugar for running interactively? Is it just for easy printing?

Comment: You've not defined a function in your swift example, rather a multi-line variable definition

Comment: I don't see how this could help you to achieve anything else than poor readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Variable lookup and attribute lookup are completely separate mechanisms in Python. What is possible in one is not necessarily possible in the other, and in this case, there is no equivalent of `property` for variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is one hacky way if your usage is only to write your property out in a  command-line, but you always get a string (and you can do any evaluations in addition). I sometimes use this for making nifty command-line syntax sugar when running interactive shells. This is to override the `__repr__` method of a wrapper class (your property maker in the question's terms):

```
queue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


class currentQueueProp:
    def __init__(self, transform=lambda x: x):
        self.transform = transform

    def __repr__(self, transform = lambda x: x):
        return str(self.transform(queue[0]))


current = currentQueueProp()
twice_current = currentQueueProp(lambda x: 2*x)

queue[0] = 3

print(current, twice_current) # What you expect
```

do note that `current` and `twice_current` are your class, and not the current value of the queue. This can get confusing since

```
>>> x = twice_current
>>> x
```

will appear to show `3` (continuing from the previous example), but of course, `x` is of type `currentQueueProp`, and you cannot use arithmetic on it etc:

```
f(x) # Not equivalent to f(3)
```